# Travis not publish release to Github

Tags: github, deployment, travis-ci

I try to setup Github release on TravisCI. For test, i've add this settings on my .travis.yml file :

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  tag_name: $TRAVIS_TAG
  target_commitish: $TRAVIS_COMMIT
  name: $TRAVIS_TAG
  api_key: $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN
  file: 'packages/mobile/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: travis-ci
```

I've set my branch name for test the deploy. But after all stage finished, I have no deployment, no error.

Is deploy work with tags only ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the draft option is missing (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/#draft-releases-with-draft-true). Can you try to edit you `.travis.yml` file to add `draft: true`, like that :

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  tag_name: $TRAVIS_TAG
  target_commitish: $TRAVIS_COMMIT
  name: $TRAVIS_TAG
  api_key: $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN
  file: 'packages/mobile/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
  draft: true
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: travis-ci
```

Let me know if it helped you :)